# I want to write in a file with two elements by line. But my program does not work. The output file is always empty

Tags: java

I want to write in a file with two elements by line. But my program does not work. The output file is always empty

```
while ((ligne = br.readLine()) != null) {
    try {
        buffer = ligne.getBytes();
        ligne = reverseMaskingService.conceal(encryptId, InitVectorMode.BIJECTIVE, buffer);
        System.out.println("ligne  : " + ligne  + ";");
        chaine += ligne + "\n";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    try {
        File fileout = new File(source + File.separator + "file.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter (fileout);
        BufferedWriter  bw = new BufferedWriter (fw);
        PrintWriter fileout1 = new PrintWriter(bw);
        fileout1.println(chaine + ";" + ligne);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
br.close();
```

Comment: For each input line, you are opening a new FileWriter. FileWriter, by default, overwrite the output file if it exists, so you only will get the last input tline in the output file. If the last input line is empty, you will get a empty output file.
Try with the second parameter "append" a true in "new FileWriter ( fileout, true);"

Comment: or just create the FileWriter outside the loop, you will prevent much overhead that way ;) (creating objects takes some time, especially when talking about I/O-stream objects)

Comment: I create the FileWriter outside the loop but fileout is always empty